# Can sequential queries result in concurrent transactions?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.4, concurrency, jdbc

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and the default configuration. I use a JDBC connection to run multiple queries in succession. Only one Java thread is using the connection and before a new query is executed the result set of the former one is fetched. Below a simplified sketch:

```
while(true) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = //...
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    //process result
}
```

The query that is causing trouble invokes the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_top_message(_queue_id BIGINT
                                            , _source_client_id BIGINT)
 RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
   DECLARE rv TEXT;
   BEGIN
     DELETE FROM message m
     USING (
        SELECT * FROM message
        WHERE message.queue_id = _queue_id
        AND (message.receiver_client_id = _source_client_id OR
             message.receiver_client_id = -1)
        ORDER BY insertion_time ASC LIMIT 1) AS tmp
     WHERE m.id = tmp.id
     RETURNING m.content INTO rv;

     IF (SELECT rv IS NULL) THEN
       RAISE 'No message available.';
     END IF;
     RETURN rv;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am observing behavior as it is described here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html in the section 13.2.1. Read Committed Isolation Level.

What happens is that the exception in the procedure is triggered although when I abort everything when the exception happens and invoke the procedure manually the exception is not raised. I noticed further that if a transaction is already holding a row exclusive lock on the message table that then the exception is raised.

Also if I add

```
     LOCK TABLE message IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

at the beginning of the procedure the problem disappears.

I thus suspect that in the above loop that a query is returning a result before its transaction is actually committed such that the next transaction is conflicting with it. Can that happen? N.B. I did not find something that explains this in the PostgreSQL documentation. Also I don't have Async commit enabled.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html - I guess you disable autocommit, but don't actually commit anything.  Is this the case?

Comment: No. I'm using default setting i.e. autocommit is enabled and I also verified that changes happen in the database.

Comment: Please provide your precise table definition and clarify whether your user is the only one writing to the table. I fixed a syntax error in your function def that's mostly likely orthogonal to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in the title: ***No.***

Consecutive queries in the same session (same transaction or not) are *never* concurrent. And there can only be *one* transaction at a time in the same session. Concurrency issues are impossible that way, those only happen between transactions in *multiple* sessions.

One possible reason for your error message might be a glitch in your function, which can be simplified:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_top_message(_queue_id bigint
                                            , _source_client_id bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   DELETE FROM message m
   USING (
      SELECT id
      FROM   message
      WHERE  queue_id = _queue_id
      AND    receiver_client_id IN (_source_client_id, -1)
      ORDER  BY insertion_time
      LIMIT  1
      ) m1
   WHERE  m.id = m1.id
   RETURNING m.content;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE 'No message available.';
   END IF;
 END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Your original check:

```
IF (SELECT rv IS NULL) THEN
```

could be simplified to:

```
IF rv IS NULL THEN
```

But that's still no good. It fires when `message.content` is NULL, not only when no row has been found. The table definition is missing in the question, so we don't know if that's possible.

Either way, the special variable `FOUND` is the better tool for the purpose. My audited version is also simpler and faster. Note that plpgsql functions do not return results until the end of the function or `RETURN` is reached. We can just return rows and still cancel the result later if need be. There is an [example in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN60573), which is a spin-off from this related question on SO:

- [FUNCTION syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731425/939860)

Comment: Because you stated it is impossible to have more than one transaction running concurrently in one session I checked again and I could not reproduce the error (which was consistently occurring when I asked the question). I thus assume that I messed something up in my setup that day. Thank you for the extended answer and all the hints!